# Box plots Error - Box portion not highlighted and Data not really sensible - Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have created a box plot but the graph does not highlight the box area for all the categories. I am not sure what the problem is. Also, the values for median , lower hinge and minimum value shows zero for most of the categories.

Comment: Can you share some more details?

Comment: I was thinking of attaching the screenshot to explain this. Is there a way to attach an image here? The box plot basically has box and whiskers; box highlights the centre-ish area and the whiskers either extend from lower end to upper end or till 1.5 quartile region in tableau. The problem is the box area is not highlighted and the values ( median / lower hinge/minimum) are Zero . Can't explain better than this .

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268469/why-cant-users-with-less-than-10-reputation-points-add-images-while-asking-ques